# How do I replace glass in a non-insulated window for my storage building?

Tags: windows, glass, window-frame

I have a non insulated window that unfortunately the glass was broken. I’m trying to figure out with not having to change the whole window ….. how can I replace the glass. But just by making this thread, I don’t know where how or where to start.

It’s a window that came with my storage building that I didn’t want to change if that helps. [image]

Answer (score 7):

Looks like an aluminum framed storm window.

Get the sash out and take it to a hardware store or glass company. *Or stop and take more pictures of both sides if you want to tackle it yourself. Can't see enough here and you have to get it out either way.*

Usually that's raise it up, pull the locks in to free them from the tracks and pull the bottom to the inside, then twist the whole thing to release the top from the tracks. There could be other methods as it's not actually a storm window, but it's a cheap aluminum frame window built rather LIKE a storm window. Look to see if there's anything to manipulate on the top of the sash, for instance.

Consider plastic if the breakage is likely to be repeated. (Vandals, golf course, etc...) Glass is likely cheaper if not.